# Javascript pop up window - need to create class and bind event to every element returned by document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I made a pop up window on my site and it is assigned to three buttons but I have the same ID on all buttons so when I click the third button to open the pop-up it is giving me the first pop-up, same with the second button.

I put a similar question to this up already but with the feedback and answers I got, I couldn't implement them as I am new to javascript and do not have much experience so I was trying to fix it for hours and I am still having no luck.

here is the javascript:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");

var showModal = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
};

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', showModal, false);
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    }
```

Here is the html:

```
<footer class="panel-footer">
  <div class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default">
    <button id="myBtn">Sign up now</button>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span class="close">×</span>
          <h2><img src="http://localhost:8383/homepage/img/logo.png" style="width:250px"></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <h4><b><u>Sign up for a basic subscription</u></b></h4><br>
          <form method="post" action="contact_basic.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
            <div class="results"></div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only">Name</label>
                  <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
                  <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email" required>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only">Phone Number</label>
                  <input name="phone" type="number" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="sr-only">Organization Name</label>
                  <input name="orgName" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Organization Name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                <button id="submit" type="submit" align="center" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">Send</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/22252/)**

The `id` attribute should be unique in same document, so you could just replace those ids by `class` attribute, e.g :

```
<button id="myBtn">Sign up now</button>
```

Will be :

```
<button class="myBtn">Sign up now</button>
```

Then in your js attach click event to all elements with this class :

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");

var showModal = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
};

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', showModal, false);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Zakaria. It did work and the pop-up now opens on all buttons, but when I open the pop-up on the second and third button, it opens the same pop-up from the first button, also the pop-up won't close when it's opened so I have to refresh the page, I will try to fix this but if you know a quick fix for this let me know :) Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome bro, glad i could helps, do you have several modals with same `id`?

Comment: So I changed the code so now it closes on click, but when I click the three pop-ups I am still getting the first one.

The forms have the same id in the html. I tried creating a class for the forms but It wasn't working out for me. I was thinking maybe I could throw in an if statement to determine which id the pop-up gets.

I will put my javascript changes in the question now

Comment: Good job, checking with you.. Also if you could create a fiddle contain the full code with the other forms so i can check it. if you want edit and update this one https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/22243/.

Comment: :) good job pass me the link now it will be updated in the bar address..

Comment: I will be sure to vote up!

I would also like to add a close event for when the user presses the send button on the form when the form is filled out, I will give it a shot but if you are up for it then work away! 

Thank you for your help anyway Zakaria, I'm under a lot of pressure to get it done and to have gotten this far is great.

Comment: You're welcome @Ashton if the form submited the modal will disappear automatically beause it will redirect you to the action.